Issue with Firebase/Firestore and React Native: TypeError: 0,_firestore.defaul is not a function (it is undefined)
I've been developing an app and for now want to integrate firestore as a database for it. I'm already using firebase for authentication/users.
When I open the page that uses firestore a "Console Warning" appears which reads the following:
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: 0,_firestore.default is not a function (it is undefined)
Even though I get the error there is activity shown on the firebase dashboard:
I have not found any post on this error and don't know what I can do to solve this.
I am using the following versions of important libraries libraries:
firebase 10.11.0
react 18.2.0
react-native 0.73.6
expo 50.0.17
Also I am not using @react-native-firebase.
I have downloaded the appropriate google-service.json and have linked my android application with firebase.
The following is my build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'

        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('com.google.gms.google-services')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

And the following is the file in which I am trying to use firestore having excluded styling:

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import firestore from "firebase/firestore";


const NewsScreen = () => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArticles = async () => {
      const articlesSnapshot = await firestore().collection('articles').get();
      const articlesData = articlesSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      setArticles(articlesData);
    };

    fetchArticles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>News</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={articles}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.articleItem}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }} style={styles.thumbnail} />
            <View style={styles.articleContent}>
              <Text style={styles.articleTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.teaserText}>{item.teaser}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};


export default NewsScreen;

This may not be relevant but I have also changed two lines in the MainApplication.kt file under "android/app/src/main/java/MainApplication.kt".
The change is the addition of the two following lines:
import expo.modules.ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher
import expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapper```

I've tried changing the Syntax on the file but to no avail.
Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help!
